# Dynamically change CSS in the head using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have some template themes. and based on those themes, when I select any themes I want to change CSS file in the head, which has also the same name as the theme. I want to do it angular way.

Here are designList and update design function.->

```
$scope.designList = ['136', '140', '150', '139', '137', '086', '088', '104', '008', '106', '002'];
$scope.updateDesign = function (design) {
            $scope.websiteContent.globalPage.settings.template = design;
            angular.element("link#designID").attr("href", $scope.templateBasePath + "design/" + design + "/css/" + design + ".css");
};
```

Here is my design html->

```
<div>
    <h2 class="helvetica designSelect">Select Design</h2>
    <div id="selectThumbs" class="paging">
        <a href="#" class="design{{design}}" ng-repeat="design in designList">
            <img class="designthumb" ng-src="{{trustSrc(templateBasePath + 'design/thumbs/' + design + '.jpg')}}" ng-click="updateDesign(design)">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In index.html->

```
<link href="app/webapp/templates/design/136/css/136.css" rel="stylesheet" id="designID">
```

right now it's built using jquery but not working though. But  I donot want to keep this. I want to use if there is any way using angular. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/angular-css-injector for this.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular.css.injector'])
.controller('myCtrl', ['cssInjector', '$scope', function(cssInjector, $scope) {
  cssInjector.add("style.css");

  $scope.changeCss = function () {
    cssInjector.removeAll();
    cssInjector.add("style1.css");
  }
}])
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2nNzQD7zKGCBSAltrrV4?p=preview

Comment: is there a bower package of this injector?

Comment: It didnot work. I followed readme.md but I saw nothing was added in head. 

`cssInjector.add($scope.templateBasePath + "design/" + design + "/css/" + design + ".css");`

Comment: i modified answer with a plnkr

Comment: Thank you for helping.
Actually I need something that will change template css file reference in head. When a new theme is selected, css file for that theme (theme name and css file name are same) will be added in place of previous file.

Comment: So you can use `cssInjector.removeAll();` to remove added css files and then add new

Comment: I modified the plnkr with the change css function

Comment: Does this cssInjector retain the css when refreshing page? Another question is that I want to write this css to link in head inside index.html. Can you help in this matter?

Comment: If You talking about saving selected css theme (for your solution) then no. You should save it in local storage or cookie. And i am not sure what did you mean in second question.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did not ask in the right way. What I wanted to ask you by that question is that if I want to add that css in link inside head tag, 
`<link href="app/webapp/templates/design/136/css/136.css" rel="stylesheet" id="designID">`, is there a way using angular?

Comment: if You want to change `href` attr directly in the `<link>` tag, i'm not sure if it is possible.